# line break in d3 tag Cloud

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I am using it to generate a heavy amount of words in my application and I grab data from a json file like below:

```
var a = [];

    for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++){
            a.push(a[i].word);
        }
```

And this gives us an array.

```
a = ["gsad","sagsa","gsag","sagas","gsag","gsagas","yhff","gag"];
```

I have it display on the screen correctly but since the row is too long it got out from the border and I'd like to give it a link break instead of change the SVG size, How may i do this?

UPDATE:

The code below is how i insert my codes:

var PositiveArr = ["gsad","sagsa","gsag","sagas","gsag","gsagas","yhff","gag"]; //consider the NegativeArr,NeutralArr have the similar contents

```
var fill = d3.scale.category20();
                  d3.layout.cloud().size([600, 300])
                      .words([NegativeArr,NeutralArr,PositiveArr].map(function(d) {
                        return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 50};
                      }))
                      .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
                      .font("Impact")
                      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
                      .on("end", draw)
                      .start();


                  function draw(words) {
                    d3.select("#pre-theme").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 600)
                        .attr("height", 300)
                      .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(300,150)")
                      .selectAll("text")
                        .data(words)
                      .enter().append("text")
                        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
                        .style("font-family",  "Impact, Arial")
                        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
                        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                          return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                        })
                        .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
                  }
```

SOLUTION:
I have found myself a solution, i just merge all my arrays into one using

```
var allResult = PersonsArr.concat(PlacesArr,PatternsArr,ProductsArr,CompaniesArr);
```

and insert the to the .map like

```
.words(entityResult.map(function(d) {
                        return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 50};
                      }))
```

Comment: you need to use `tspan` inside text element for linebreak or use `foreignobject`. Show your complete code which appends the tags

Comment: is there any example or relevant document about this method? thank you.

Comment: Post your complete code. where you add this tags and how ?

Comment: i have updated my code please take a look. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:** I have found myself a solution, i just merge all my arrays into one using

```
var allResult = PersonsArr.concat(PlacesArr,PatternsArr,ProductsArr,CompaniesArr);
```

and insert the to the .map like

```
.words(entityResult.map(function(d) {
                        return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 50};
                      }))
```